# How to translate Python's OS exit codes to their string values

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I translate Python's os exit codes to their string equivalent?

For example,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.EX_OSERR
71
```

I want to take the integer 71 and derive the name 'EX_OSERR'.

I don't want to go through the trouble of creating any sort of lookup for each value.  I'm looking for a solution using Python's builtins, or a method within the standard modules, if possible.

I'm interested in a solution for python 2.X.

Comment: Nobody uses any sort of standardized exit values.

Comment: But if I know its a flavor os.EX_*, then I want an easy way to translate the integer value back to its string equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've come up with is to create a lookup dictionary:

```
import os
osexit_dict = {}
for exit_name  in [x for x in dir(os) if x.startswith('EX')]:
   exit_num = getattr(os, exit_name)
   osexit_dict[exit_num] = exit_name
```

Although this doesn't completely satisfy the question, since its creating a lookup (even though its easy to do).

Maybe someone else can come up with a way to use Python's built-ins.

Comment: What is `signal` here?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this: import signal.  I'll make the edit to the answer above.

Comment: Sorry @Rahul. That was a typo. Everywhere it says 'signal' it should say 'os'. I was writing some other code and mixed this up when I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this but this will work.

```
d = {attrgetter(value)(os) : value for value in dir(os) if value.startswith('EX')}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is similar to my answer provided.

Comment: You are using signal additionally. I don't know what it does. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry @Rahul.  That was a typo.  Everywhere it says 'signal' it should say 'os'.  I was writing some other code and mixed this up when I posted it here.